# Dojox.charting.themes define number of colors

Tags: dojox.charting

I’m using MiamiNice theme in my “pie’s” graphics, but doesn’t provide enough colors, and repeat colors in some sectors, is there any way to define a number of colors?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create your own Theme and put there all the colors that you want.

e.g.

```
var myTheme = new dojox.charting.Theme({
            colors: [
                    "#A4CE67",
                    "#739363",
                    "#6B824A",
                    "#343434",
                    "#636563"
            ]
    });
```

Then you should use "myTheme" as your theme in your chart.